# Gnuplot default line color rgb values

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 5.2 and would like to get the rgb values associated with the default line colors. Using the command `test` I get a nice summary of available options and parameters but the default colors are just labelled by `1, 2, 3, ....` and the rgb values are not shown. The command `show colors` is useful too, but that only shows the names of the colors and the rgb values, but not the labels `1, 2, 3, ...` so I don't know which is which.

My goal is to use the default line colors and plot lines with transparency. From other questions here I learned that this is possible with version 5.2 by the color specificifaction `lc rgb #aarrggbb` but for this I need to know the rgb values.

And there doesn't seem to be a straightforward text configuration file for gnuplot containing the default line colors (I'm on fedora), `rpm -ql gnuplot` does not show any such config file, so I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
gnuplot> show linetype

        linetype 1,  linecolor rgb "dark-violet"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 1 pointsize default
        linetype 2,  linecolor rgb "#009e73"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 2 pointsize default
        linetype 3,  linecolor rgb "#56b4e9"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 3 pointsize default
        linetype 4,  linecolor rgb "#e69f00"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 4 pointsize default
        linetype 5,  linecolor rgb "#f0e442"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 5 pointsize default
        linetype 6,  linecolor rgb "#0072b2"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 6 pointsize default
        linetype 7,  linecolor rgb "#e51e10"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 7 pointsize default
        linetype 8,  linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid pointtype 8 pointsize default
        Linetypes repeat every 8 unless explicitly defined
```

Answer (score 2):

In gnuplot 5.2 on you get the rgb color values from the current palette into the datablock `$PALETTE` via `test palette`. Check `help palette`.

So if you do:

```
test palette
print $PALETTE
```

you will get...

```
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
0.0039 0.0626 0.0000 0.0246 0.0215 
0.0078 0.0886 0.0000 0.0493 0.0321 
0.0118 0.1085 0.0000 0.0739 0.0409 
0.0157 0.1252 0.0000 0.0984 0.0487 
0.0196 0.1400 0.0000 0.1229 0.0559 
...
0.4941 0.7029 0.1206 0.0370 0.2852 
0.4980 0.7057 0.1235 0.0123 0.2849 
0.5020 0.7085 0.1265 0.0000 0.2861 
0.5059 0.7113 0.1295 0.0000 0.2887 
0.5098 0.7140 0.1325 0.0000 0.2913 
0.5137 0.7167 0.1356 0.0000 0.2939 
0.5176 0.7195 0.1387 0.0000 0.2965 
...
0.9725 0.9862 0.9199 0.0000 0.8348 
0.9765 0.9882 0.9311 0.0000 0.8420 
0.9804 0.9901 0.9423 0.0000 0.8492 
0.9843 0.9921 0.9537 0.0000 0.8565 
0.9882 0.9941 0.9651 0.0000 0.8638 
0.9922 0.9961 0.9767 0.0000 0.8711 
0.9961 0.9980 0.9883 0.0000 0.8785 
1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 0.0000 0.8860
```

Then it depends on what you exactly want to do with it.

**Addition:**

Ok, you are talking about the colors which appear if you type `test`, correct?
That's what I get with a wxt terminal.

[image]

There is a file in the gnuplot subfolder `share` called `colors_default.gp`.

```
# Ethan A Merritt - my preference for gnuplot colors
# 2 3 4 5 6 8 are borrowed from the colors_podo set
#
set linetype  1 lc rgb "dark-violet" lw 1
set linetype  2 lc rgb "#009e73" lw 1
set linetype  3 lc rgb "#56b4e9" lw 1
set linetype  4 lc rgb "#e69f00" lw 1
set linetype  5 lc rgb "#f0e442" lw 1
set linetype  6 lc rgb "#0072b2" lw 1
set linetype  7 lc rgb "#e51e10" lw 1
set linetype  8 lc rgb "black"   lw 1
set linetype  9 lc rgb "gray50"  lw 1
set linetype cycle  9
```

where:

```
dark-violet = #9400d3
black       = #000000
```

However, apparently, the colors (in the test screen) are repeated with a cycle of 8.

Comment: I guess we are talking about two different things. There is the color palette and the default colors for lines. Which one do you need? I'm not sure where to get the rgb values for the default line colors, but with linestyle (and index number) you can define any color you want. Check `help linestyle`.