# Use default linecolor as textcolor

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot has some default color for lines.

How can I call those colors with `textcolor`? What are their name/identifier?

I try to do something like this:

```
set ylabel 'A' textcolor 'linecolor1'
set ylabel 'B' textcolor 'linecolor2'
```

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136226/gnuplot-default-line-color-rgb-values), but I want to avoid extracting the values by myself and call their identifier instead.

Comment: What do you mean with values and what do you mean with identifiers? Maybe the corresponding pair `0x9400d3` and `dark-violet`, respectively?

Comment: In your example, `0x9400d3` is the value, `dark-violet` is the identifier pointing to the value. I would like to have the identifier of value of the color of the line 1, 2, etc.

Comment: not every code/value has an identifier/name. There are only 111 pre-defined gnuplot "named" colors. See them visualized here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `help colorspec`. I guess you are looking for something like this:

**Code:**

```
### linecolors as textcolors
reset session

set label 1 at graph 0.2, 0.6 "Linecolor 1" tc lt 1
set label 2 at graph 0.2, 0.7 "Linecolor 2" tc lt 2
set label 3 at graph 0.2, 0.8 "Linecolor 3" tc lt 3
set label 4 at graph 0.2, 0.9 "Linecolor 4" tc lt 4
set key top left
plot x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried `linetype 1` instead of `lt 1`. `linetype 1` didn't work.

Comment: @Narann interesting. The documentation clearly says that `linetype 1` should also work. A bug in the documentation!?